# Excel - Writing 's in a cell automatically writes 'ss

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I've recently noticed something weird in excel. Every time I write a word that ends with 's it automatically updates it to 'ss. If I delete the extra s it adds it straight back in upon leaving the cell. How do I turn this behaviour off?

Changing cell formatting does not remove the issue, I've tried text, general, even setting it as a number.

Example: ID's becomes ID'ss

Comment: does this happen with a new workbook, or just the one you are currently using?

Comment: and does it only happen in Excel?

Comment: Have you checked your **Spelling Correction Settings** ??

Comment: @ScottCraner All workbooks, be they created new on my excel or created by somebody else and opened in my excel.

Comment: What version of Excel? What OS version? FYI, I tried in Excel 2010 under Win10 and I do _not_ see that behavior.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent - First thing I checked was word's auto-correction options and there's nothing there for it. The issue doesn't appear in other MS products like word or Outlook (I'm using word renderer in outlook)

Comment: @yoshm 
Excel 2007 (12.0.6683.5002 SP3 MSO (12.0.6683.5000). 
Windows 7 SP1

Comment: @Dave - Yep, only happening in Excel.

Comment: What if you type `ID's `? (note the trailing space) does it stay as `ID's ` with `len() = 5`?

Comment: Sounds like user error and not Excel. Are you using AHK, modified mouse controls, modified keyboard? Software is at play, but not Excel. Gaming strategies with shortcuts? PC gamer? Are you saving your sheet. There are literally a million and one reasons. Troubleshoot your input devices.

Comment: That is what I thought @ejbytes hence why I asked if it only happens with Excel...  pix1985, does it happen if you start Excel in safe mode? Is this a macro enabled workbook?

Comment: I happened to check something out that you might want to check. I used ABC check in Excel, and it seems that the "Custom Word List" is a global list shared by all MS Suite (Word, Outlook, Excel, etc). To check out your custom list follow this in Excel: Review Tab -> Proofing ->Custom Dictionairies -> "Roaming Custom.dic" or "Custom.dic" and Select Edit Word List. As to why it would automatically change it could be that you have auto-correct set up? And those two things combined would could be the reason of your question; Among the other things I mentioned in my initial comment above.